# Height of dropdown box in multiselect option

Tags: javascript, html, multi-select

Im using multiselect dropdown for my select control. Im adding options to select control in Javascript. Reading data from database through PHP and passing to javascript file. But the height of the options dropdown is small like i can only see 'Select All' check box with out any scrolling. But if i add the options in HTML itself, then the dropdown looks fine. What im missing here?

```
 <script src="<?=BASE_URL?>dropdown/multiple-select.js"></script>
    <link href="<?=BASE_URL?>dropdown/multiple-select.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="modal" id="SendmailModel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="messageModelLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content"> 
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><li class="fa fa-times"/></button>
        <h3 style="font-size: 17px;">Send Mail </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="mailcomposeForm" id="_id_">
            <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Event Details</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped" id="event_days_table" style="display: none;width:544px;font-size:14px;">
                <tbody id="event_days_table_body">
                </tbody>
                </table>    
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="leave_status">Select Recipient(s)</label>             
                <select   id="emplist" name="employee_name" value="" multiple="multiple">

                </select>

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="modJs.SendingMail();">Send</button>
        <button class="btn" onclick="modJs.closemaildialog();">Not Now</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


    script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() { 
    $('#emplist').change(function() {

            }).multipleSelect({
                width: '100%',
                height:'100%'
            });
    });
            </script>
```

In my Javascript file..

```
Conferencelisting.method('MailSuccessCallback', function(callBackData) {

    var row = '<tr><th>From</th><td>_from_</td></tr><tr><th>To</th><td>_to_</td></tr><tr><th>Type</th><td>_type_</td></tr><tr><th>Created By</th><td>_created_</td><tr><th>Details</th><td>_details_</td></tr>';

    var eventdetails = callBackData[0];
    var html = "";  
    var trow = "";          
    for(var i=0;i<eventdetails.length;i++){
        trow = row;
        trow = trow.replace(/_from_/g,Date.parse(eventdetails[i].From).toString('d MMM yyyy <b>h:mm tt</b>'));
        trow = trow.replace(/_to_/g,Date.parse(eventdetails[i].To).toString('d MMM yyyy  <b>h:mm tt</b>'));
        trow = trow.replace(/_type_/g,eventdetails[i].type);
        trow = trow.replace(/_created_/g,eventdetails[i].employee);
        trow = trow.replace(/_details_/g,eventdetails[i].reason);
        html += trow;
    }
    $('#event_days_table_body').html(html);
    $('#event_days_table').show();  

//Adding employees name in selection box.

    var emplist = callBackData[1];
    var options = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < emplist.length; i++) {
    options += '<option value="' + emplist[i].id + '">' + emplist[i].name+ '</option>';
    } 

    $("#emplist").html(options);    
    $('#SendmailModel').modal('show');      
});
```

If i add options in HTML file like this..i can get exact dropdown with scrolls..

```
<select   id="emplist" name="employee_name" value="" multiple="multiple">
 <option value="ALEX">ALEX</option>
  <option value="BOB">BOB</option>
  <option value="DE">DE</option>                
                </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved myself. I think the height is not the problem , the data are not getting added. SO i changed options adding code in javascript file. Now it works.

```
var emplist = callBackData[1];
    var options = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < emplist.length; i++) {
    $('#emplist').append( '<option value="' + emplist[i].id + '">' + emplist[i].name+ '</option>' );
    }   
    $('#emplist').multipleSelect( 'refresh' );
```